# How to target inner classes in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ckeditor

I want to access cke_editable class in the body tag.
My own defined class is .feed-ckeditor.

I am using the below CSS to access the inner class.

```css
.feed-ckeditor {
    .cke_chrome {
        border: none !important;

        .cke_contents {
            height: 100px !important;

        }
    }

    body .cke_editable{
            font-size: 20px !important;
            line-height: 1.6;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        
    }

    .cke_bottom {
        border-top: 1px solid #c9c9c94d !important;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c94d !important;
    }
}
```

I am not able to make a font size 20px of the CKEditor text area.

The below image shows the nested hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe . Basically setting the css in an iframe is not that simple. If you still can't make it work based on the link please provide a minimal working example